# How do I install Chrome OS?

Tags: operating-systems

Could I get Chrome OS working on my Raspberry Pi without having to compile anything?

I've heard somebody has compiled it for the Raspberry Pi, so I was wondering if anyone has had any experience in doing this.

Comment: Hi Nathan, Welcome to Stack Exchange. Why do you want to use Chrome OS?

Comment: I was thinking of buying a chromebook so wanted to test out the OS on my Raspberry Pi

Comment: I would say no, as a simple solution and Yes but it's complex as.  Android might be better to go for because the RPi is a phone chip. And it does all that Chrome OS can do.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Yes, but you have to compile it.

Hexxeh has been working on a build for the Raspberry Pi, as outlined in this [blog post](http://hexxeh.net/?p=328117867). The main issue with it is that it is *really, really, slow.* This is because there is no graphical acceleration.

## Prerequisites

It is recommended that you have the following things before attempting to build Chromium OS.

1. A 64-bit build machine, running Ubuntu version 10.04 (other
    versions/distros might work, but aren't supported, you're on your own)
2. At least 4GB of RAM.
3. A fast Internet connection.

## Get the Code

Now you need to get the actual Chromium OS code. You can find out how to do this at the [Chromium OS Developer Guide](http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/developer-guide).

## Add the Overlay

Next you need to add the Raspberry Pi overlay to the source code. Find the directory named `overlays` in the `src` folder of the Chromium OS source code. Copy the overlay found in the [Hexxeh/overlay-raspberrypi](https://github.com/Hexxeh/overlay-raspberrypi) Github repro.

## Toolchain Setup

First you **must** be inside the Chromium OS chroot. Refer to sectoin 4.2 of the developer guide if you are not sure how to do this. Second you need to be root to build the toolchain. This can be achieved via `su` or `sudo -i`. Then run the following command.

```
$ USE="-thumb -hardened hardfp" FEATURES="splitdebug" crossdev -S -t armv6j-cros-linux-gnueabi --ex-gdb
```

Now we can quit root via `exit`.

## Board Setup

You only need to run this command once.

```
$ ./setup_board --board=raspberrypi
```

You'll also want to leave a backdoor for a development image to let yourself into the shell. You can do that via the following command.

```
$ ./set_shared_user_password
```

At the prompt enter the password and press enter. Tada.

## Building an Image

First we need to make sure that we have all the required packages. We can get build these via.

```
$ ./build_packages --board=raspberrypi --withdev --nowithdebug --nousepkg --nowithautotest
```

Finally! You can build a USB image via.

```
$ ./build_image dev --board=raspberrypi --noenable_rootfs_verification
```

## References

1. [Overlay Raspberry Pi README](https://raw.github.com/Hexxeh/overlay-raspberrypi/master/README.md)

Comment: Nice- Does it work? :-) hehehe

Comment: @ppumkin I don't personally have a Raspberry Pi, but I hear that yes. Yes, it does work. =P

Comment: The `Hexxeh/overlay-raspberrypi` github repo no longer exists. Any alternative forks of that repo? Would [this one](https://github.com/m943040028/chromiumos_overlay) be adequate?

Comment: for googling wanderers, Hexxeh project is discontinued, and you need Ubuntu 14.10 to build Chrome OS

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at http://hexxeh.net/. He has been working on a build. There are some BETA files you can download and compile but no full image has been released to date.